# How to disable NativescriptTheme in a specific BottomNav Tabs component?

Tags: ios, vue.js, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I'm trying to style my Tabs of the `BottomNavigation` but I'm not being able to do it because of a Nativescript Theme globally installed.
For example, my BottomNav Tab label is being filled with a Nativescript Theme global style, probably for titles, or labels... well, I don't know.

[image]

Here is my example... The "Home", because it's selected, should be black. But it's lime because of a globally installed Nativescript Theme.

How could I effectively set this to be black when selected?

I already tried to use CSS:

```
TabStrip {
    background-color: $primary;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

TabStripItem {
    color: white;
}

TabStripItem:active {
    color: black;
}

TabStripItem Label {
    font-size: 12;
}
```

But didn't worked.
Also, I tried to set the color to this `TabStripItem Label` and worked but only to be always black. I wish that it could be set dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I've found it.

I needed to just set this CSS:

```
TabStripItem:active Label {
    color: black;
}
```